# ORACLE SQL retrieve n rows without subqueries or derived tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions, row-number

I'm doing my SQL exercises but I got stuck in one. I need to retrieve the employees with the two highest salaries, but I can't use any type of subquery or derived table. I do it with a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY sal DESC) new_emp
WHERE ROWNUM < 3;
```

I also know that this can be achieved using the `WITH` clause, but I'm wondering if there is any alternative to this.

PS: I'm using Oracle 11.

Comment: Technically that's not a "sub-query" but a derived table. Which Oracle version are you using? With Oracle 12 you can use the ANSI SQL `fetch first 3 rows only`

Comment: You are using inline View. When you have a query in the where clause, it is a subquery.

Comment: Yes I know, we can't also use derived tables (I forgot to mention this, sorry). I'm using Oracle 11

Comment: What should happen if more than two employees have the same (max) salary? Or one has the highest and two have the same next-to-highest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pathetic method, in my opinion, but you can use a `join`:

```
select e.col1, e.col2, . . .
from emp e left join
     emp e2
     on e2.salary >= e.salary
group by e.col1, e.col2, . . .
having count(distinct e2.salary) <= 2;
```

Note:  this is really equivalent to a `dense_rank()`, so if there are ties, you'll get more than two rows.  It is easy enough to fix this (assuming you have a unique identifier for each row), but the fix complicates the logic and hides the basic idea.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I also tried the `dense_rank()` function and the where clause, but it's not working together, so this is like the `dense_rank()` function and works absolutely fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice solution and realy the only one complying the restriction.

Answer (score 2):

If you are Oracle version 12.1 or above you can use  a row limiting clause. In your case you would just use the subquery plus the row limiting clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM emp 
ORDER BY sal DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Source: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1#top-n

Comment: Hi, I'm using Oracle 11

Comment: Hi Elias, I added an answer using an analytics function. Let me know if it works!

Comment: There is no from clause in your updated query and if you fix that you will then get `ORA-00904: "SAL_RANK": invalid identifier` as there is no `sal_rank` column in `Emp` and the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the selected columns are generated.

Answer (score 1):

A *good exercise* should help to prepare to solve practical problems. So the **important thing** in this one is *not the usage of subquery* but to realize that the two highes salaries can have hunderts of employees.

While using the @MT0 **view workaround** this is the query

```
CREATE VIEW sal_ordered_emps AS
  SELECT e.*,
  row_number() over (order by sal desc) as RN
  FROM   SCOTT.emp e
  ORDER BY sal DESC;

select e.* from scott.emp e join 
sal_ordered_emps soe on e.sal = soe.sal and rn <= 2
;
```

result as explained can be more than 2 records

```
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19.04.1987 00:00:00       3000                    20 
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981 00:00:00       5000                    10 
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.1981 00:00:00       3000                    20
```

Comment: This uses a subquery.

Comment: @Gordon you are right, but a light violation of the - not very meaninfull -  rules, if leads to correct answer *might be acceptable*:)

Comment: @Gordon I decide to remove the subquery to comply the requirement - see update

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating but... instead of using a subquery you can define a view:

```
CREATE VIEW sal_ordered_emps AS
  SELECT *
  FROM   emp
  ORDER BY sal DESC;
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM sal_ordered_emps WHERE ROWNUM < 3;
```

Alternatively, you can do it with a pipelined function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_pkg
AS
  TYPE emp_table IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE;

  FUNCTION get_max_sals(
    n INT
  ) RETURN emp_table PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION get_max_sals(
    n INT
  ) RETURN emp_table PIPELINED
  AS
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    in_rec EMP%ROWTYPE;
    i INT := 0;
  BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY SAL DESC;
    LOOP
      i := i + 1;
      FETCH cur INTO in_rec; 
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND OR i > n;
      PIPE ROW(in_rec);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/

SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( emp_pkg.get_max_sals( 2 ) );
```

Comment: Yes, this is like using `WITH` clause. We aren't allowed to do it this way also...

Comment: @EliasGarciaMariño added a solution using pipelined functions... not sure if this is disallowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This solution use no subquery, but requires three steps:

```
-- Q1
select max(sal) from scott.emp;
-- Q2
select max(sal) from scott.emp where sal < {result of Q1}; 

select * from scott.emp where sal in ({result of Q1},{result of Q2});
```

General you'll need N+1 queries to get top-N salaries emps.